# Limit creation of events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've checked you can constrain some events to be dragged in a period, or to avoid to move to other periods, but I'm looking a feature to block creation of events just in the business hours defined.

Is it possible to use the "selectable: true" (to be able to create events with clicking in some time and drag to the end, as Google Calendar), but limit to some time spaces ?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting - you've got "selectAllow", "selectOverlap", "selectConstraint" which can all contribute to restricting where events can be placed. And/Or if you define "businessHours" (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours) then selections can only be made within those defined hours. Have you spent much time studying any of this documentation?

Comment: so there's no chance to join "busineshours" and "selectAllow", right ?  do i have to code a custom function in "selectAllow" to replicate "busineshours" feature ? :-(
And no ... it's not true ... businesshours still ALLOW to create events outside them

Comment: Yes, I've been reading a lot ... have you ??   "businesshours" doc: "Emphasizes certain time slots" ... it does not say "block certain time slots" ... I've tested and businesshours JUST put a grey background, nothing else

Comment: Sorry my mistake with businessHours you're right, but if you set `selectConstraint: "businessHours"` then selections will be restricted to mirror the already-defined business hours. Apologies, I always use them together so forgot it was an extra line of code.  P.S. `"there's no chance to join "busineshours" and "selectAllow" ...`what do you mean by "join" exactly?

Comment: that's exactly what I meant ... to join businesshours and selectallow (or constrain) ... selectConstraint: "businessHours"  WORKS  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a defined set of time when events will always be restricted to (without variations over time) then you can use a combination of the [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours) and [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) settings to enforce this:

```
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4], // Monday - Thursday
  startTime: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  endTime: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
},
selectConstraint: "businessHours"
```

In the above example, "businessHours" will grey-out all the areas of the calendar outside the times defined (in this case Monday to Thursday from 10am to 6pm each day). Setting "selectConstraint" to "businessHours" means that users cannot select to create new events which fall outside the same time range.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/aboqPoo